# HTML Dropdown without Class

Tags: html

I'm a super newbie at HTML and i want to know if we can create dropdown list using HTML without 'class' usage. I searched here as well as in WWW and found almost all the examples/syntax has class in it. The page where I'm trying to create a dropdown supports span, but doesn't support class. I tried the below, but it didn't work.

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button class="btn">Action</button>
<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle"><span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I Don't think this is possible, but I'm no pro myself, so I'm not 100% sure, but may I ask why don't you want to use classes?

Comment: first you should learn the basics of html.. since classes or not makes no differences.. classes are just used to help your css target the things you want to target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use select - this is the html dropdown. For more info see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

```
<select name="select">
  <option value="Action">Action</option> 
  <option value="Another action" selected>Another action</option>
  <option value="Separated link">Separated link</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ID should work too.

Why do you not wanna use 'Class'?

Comment: the page I'm coding doesn't support class :(

Comment: then you should change it, i mean, the not-use of css is outdated and really really makes your work harder. Consider changing to something else. What kind of page you are coding?